# CoronaSDK rotating a sprite smoothly

Tags: lua, sprite, coronasdk

Just looking for some advice / help on how to implement the following:

I have a path that I have set out using waypoints, when an enemy reaches a waypoint it moves on to the next one. I have set the angle of the next sprite to play in the properties for the waypoint but I need this to turn smoothly. My sprites are rendered at every 22.5 degrees upto 360 degrees and some of the paths turn at 90 degrees. So the sprite could be playing the sequence at 45 degrees and it reaches a waypoint where the next sequence to play could be 135 degree sprite. So how can i get this to turn nice and smooth rather than jumping from 45 straight to 135?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the object's rotation directly, try setting a target rotation, and then interpolating towards that.

For example:

```
--Sprite is currently rotated 45 degrees, I now want it to change to 135 degrees
mySprite.targetRotation = 135
```

Now in an enterFrame function (if you don't already have one, then you will need to add one):

```
local function Update(event)

local turnSpeed = 0.5
mySprite.rotation = mySprite.rotation +  turnSpeed * (mySprite.targetRotation - mySprite.rotation)

end
```

The turnSpeed variable should be between 0.0001 to 1 depending on how fast you want them to turn (0.0001 will mean it turns very slowly, 1 will be instant).

Given that you presumably have more than one of these sprites, you will need to put them in a table, and apply this calculation to all objects in that table.